# pip3 install inside venv is throwing "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm trying to get to grips with working inside a virtual environment, I ran the following:

```
python3 -m venv env 

source env/bin/activate

pip3 install flask
```

And it throws this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.1.1)
```

I'm on OSX and I actually have Python 3.8 installed. I'm a bit lost on this.

I remember way back, around a year ago when I was first installing Python 3.x I had quite a bit of trouble and I feel I might have messed something up during the install or something.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement satisfied means all its dependencies are installed already.

Comment: You can check by importing flask whether it's working or not

Comment: Yes, but it's checking the global site packages folder, not within the venv, surely when I pip3 install flask, it should install that into the virtual environment and not attempt to install it globally?

Comment: after activating the venv is it showing your virtual environment name;

Comment: Yes. I'll update my original but I uninstalled Python 3.7 and then everything started working fine for some reason.